# intellisense not working with tsconfig.json, babel.config.js, and .eslintrc.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I configure these `babel.config.js, tsconfig.json, and .eslintrc.json`
it working fine with project run and build but it's not showing any suggestions (intellisense) with my imports.
Please review and help me to fix it. So, visual sutio code show intellisense and I can work fast.

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['airbnb', 'airbnb/hooks', '@react-native-community'],
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: [
        ['assets', './assets'],
        ['components', './components'],
        ['screens', './screens'],
        ['utils', './utils'],
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "assets/*": ["./assets/*"],
    "components/*": ["./components/*"],
    "screens/*": ["./screens/*"],
    "utils/*": ["./utils/*"],
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          alias: {
            assets: './assets',
            components: './components',
            screens: './screens',
            utils: './utils',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: Try reloading VSCode: ctrl + shift + P, then type "reload window"

Comment: Just as a sidenote, for eslint messages in vscode, you need to install the eslint extension.

Comment: Are no import suggestions working at all, or just the one you aliased? If none are working, are just the imports not working or generally all language feature? Like, if you type "con", does it pop-up with things like "console", and "const"...?

Comment: only aliased imports are not working other imports are working fine. Yes, installed eslint extension

"@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
"@types/react": "~17.0.21",
"@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
"eslint": "^7.18.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
"eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.0.0",
"jest-expo": "^43.0.0",
"prettier": "^2.2.1",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"typescript": "~4.3.5"